# MySql: How do I insert multiple columns from multiple rows into another table?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

- I want to copy multiple columns (not all) from multiple rows in `source_table`, and create a new row in `destination_table` for each set of values from a single row.
- So in this example, 5 new rows should be created in `destination_table`, each with three of their fields set:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table (source_id, foo_id, bar) 
VALUES( 
    (SELECT id, foo_id, bar FROM source_table WHERE id=399274),
    (SELECT id, foo_id, bar FROM source_table WHERE id=399279),
    (SELECT id, foo_id, bar FROM source_table WHERE id=380409), 
    (SELECT id, foo_id, bar FROM source_table WHERE id=400037), 
    (SELECT id, foo_id, bar FROM source_table WHERE id=401026)
);
```

but this results in an error:
`ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

- I have perused many articles which deal with similar questions but cannot find an answer to this specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the insert...values syntax, use insert...select:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table (source_id, foo_id, bar) 
SELECT id, foo_id, bar FROM source_table
WHERE id in (399274,399279,380409,400037,401026);
```